# LNK2001 problem (Follow-up to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65643450/lnk2019-declspecdllimport-cdecl-issue)

Tags: qt

Note: This is the second part of the problem I'm facing. The first part is [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65643450/lnk2019-declspecdllimport-cdecl-issue)

I'm not sure how I got to this problem, but the other part is these four:

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl cm::controllers::MasterController::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@MasterController@controllers@cm@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
```

,

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl cm::controllers::MasterController::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@MasterController@controllers@cm@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
```

,

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __cdecl cm::controllers::MasterController::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@MasterController@controllers@cm@@UEAAPEAXPEBD@Z)
```

and finally,

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static struct QMetaObject const cm::controllers::MasterController::staticMetaObject" (__imp_?staticMetaObject@MasterController@controllers@cm@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
```

Something I found while searching on this was that I could get rid of all of these through removing `Q_OBJECT`, saving, then putting it back. For me, it only went away when I removed `Q_OBJECT` without putting it back. This definitely isn't a solution, just something interesting I found.

I'm using Qt Creator 5.12, by the way.

Comment: What is the difference between the posts? Why are you pointing out that it is a follow-up question?

Comment: I think in both questions you did not give us any code or a [mcve] to be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I don't think removing `Q_OBJECT` is the key to solve this.

Comment: If removing the `Q_OBJECT` macro appears to fix the symptoms then you've probably forgot to compile and link with the `moc` generated code.

Comment: @drescherjm I'm not too sure on how the error emerged.

Comment: If a totally clean build did not work and If you are using source control like git or svn you may want to revert to an earlier build when the code worked. I expect this question that it is unlikely that you will get this solved on StackOverflow in a timely manner.